# NSNotificationCenter with SpriteKit

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, nsnotificationcenter

I am using NSNotificationCenter to notify when keys are pressed on the keyboard. When moving between scenes, if an additional key is pressed too quickly after the key that causes the scene transition is pressed the app crashes. I'm not sure if it's the previous scene that no longer receives notifications or if the next scene's observer for notifications is not set up. What can I do to stop this from happening? Here's the code for two different scenes and the custom view that handles the notifications. Essentially, I'm posting a notification for key presses in `CustomSKView` and then I handle the presses in the respective scenes in a method called `keyPressed:` that is not listed here.

**LevelSelectScene.m**

```
@implementation LevelSelectScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyPressed:) name:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey" object:nil];

    //perform scene setup here
    ...
}

-(void)willMoveFromView:(SKView *)view {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey"
                                              object:nil];

    //perform additional cleanup before moving to next scene
    ...
```

}

**Menu.m**

```
-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyPressed:) name:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey" object:nil];

    //perform menu setup here
    ...
}


-(void) willMoveFromView:(SKView *)view {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey"
                                              object:nil];

    //perform additional cleanup before moving to next scene
    ...
}
```

**CustomSKView.m**

```
#import "CustomSKView.h"

@implementation CustomSKView:SKView {

}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    return self;
}

- (void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:@{@"keyCode" : @(theEvent.keyCode)}];
}

@end
```

**EDIT: Stack Trace**

```
2015-08-15 05:47:08.199 PianoKeyboardTest[21854:4643404] -[NSPathStore2 keyPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10050d110
2015-08-15 05:47:08.199 PianoKeyboardTest[21854:4643404] -[NSPathStore2 keyPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10050d110
2015-08-15 05:47:08.200 PianoKeyboardTest[21854:4643404] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8575803c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9227376e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8575b0ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff856a0e24 ___forwarding___ + 1028
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff856a0998 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8571445c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85604634 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
7   Foundation                          0x00007fff83e8e9d1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
8   PianoKeyboardTest                   0x000000010001d50e -[CustomSKView keyDown:] + 270
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8ba1c11b -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 5452
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b3add76 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 470
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b3aa9b1 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4199
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b2d3c68 -[NSApplication run] + 711
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b250354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
14  PianoKeyboardTest                   0x0000000100005322 main + 34
15  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8f1ee5c9 start + 1
)
```

**EDIT: Solution**

Here are the changes that I made to CustomSKView.

```
#import "CustomSKView.h"

@implementation CustomSKView:SKView {
    // Add instance variables here

}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        // Allocate and initialize your instance variables here

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:@{@"keyCode" : @(theEvent.keyCode)}];
}

//overridden version of SKScene's presentScene: transition: method
-(void) presentScene:(SKScene *)scene transition:(SKTransition *)transition {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.scene
                                                    name:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey"
                                                  object:nil];
    [super presentScene:scene transition:transition];
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: OK, so the stacktrace is showing that you haven't implemented your observer method (`keyPressed:`) in the `NSPathStore2` class.  However, as the name suggests, `NSPathStore2` is part of Cocoa (it's a kind of `NSString` for file paths).  So that's a bit of mystery.  Are those the only places the observer is set-up?

Comment: Oh, I see. The `keyPressed:` method is implemented in each of the scenes that require notifications. Either way, the issue is when I switch between two scenes and press a key while the transition is taking place. What I really want to do is eliminate the users ability to press register any key presses when the scene transition is taking place, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: And I guess if you don't use transitions it's OK? You might have to add the call to remove the notification before you invoke transition, as it sounds like a timing issue to me.

Comment: @trojanfoe is right. You should remove the observer before you call `presentScene`.

Comment: Thanks guys...it worked like a charm. I think the reason that I didn't do it before is that I would have to manually call a method every time I wanted to switch from scene to scene and using `willMoveToView` just seemed more elegant, but ultimately didn't work properly. @trojanfoe: please type up an answer and I'll select it. Thanks so much!

Comment: You can override `presentScene` in `CustomSKView` and remove the observer from the current scene (i.e., self.scene).

Comment: How would you do that? That actually sounds like a great idea, that way I wouldn't have to manage removing it before calling `presentScene:`

Comment: If you define a method in the custom view called presentScene: that has an SKScene as a parameter, that method will be called when presentScene is called. You can then remove the observer from self.scene.

Comment: and then call the `[super presentScene:scene];`

Comment: @0x141E you are a genius! Thanks.

Comment: @02fentym I will delete my non-answer (once you unaccept it).  It looks to me that 0x141E actually has a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an observer from the current `SKScene` whenever the game transitions to a new scene, override the `presentScene` method in your custom view class, remove the observer, and then call the super class's `presentScene`:

```
- (void) presentScene:(SKScene *)scene transition:(SKTransition *)transition {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.scene
                                                    name:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey"
                                                  object:nil];
    [super presentScene:scene transition:transition];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be timing.  You need to remove the notification before the transition starts, however `SKView` does not provide a convenient hook for this.

One possible way of managing this is to subclass `SKView` to provide the mechanism to add and remove the observers, with the possibility of using multiple notifications; one for keystrokes and the other for transition start/ends.  When a *transition start* notification is fired, this subclass will remove the keystroke observer.  When the transition has finished it could be notified to re-observe keystrokes.  However this does sound complicated.